# How can I add css transition to elements Javascript created?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, animation

I'm trying to make a randomly placed puzzle with clicking, but it looks too rigid without any transition. I want to make the shuffle movement smoother with some delay or some transitions, so I tried to add CSS transition in each list item, but it doesn't really change anything. This is what I tried. How can I add CSS property to elements JS created?

```
  <div class="wrap-all">
    <ul class="image-container">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container"></div>

<script>
const container = document.querySelector(".image-container");
const wrapAll = document.querySelector(".wrap-all");
const tileCount = 16;

let tiles = [];

setGame();

function setGame() {
  tiles = createImageTiles();
  tiles.forEach(tile => container.appendChild(tile));
}

wrapAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  const li = document.querySelector("li");
  li.style.transitionDelay = "2s";

  shuffle(tiles).forEach(tile => container.appendChild(tile));

  setTimeout(() => {
    container.innerHTML = "";
    setGame();
  }, 3000)
})

function createImageTiles() {
  const tempArray = [];
  Array(tileCount).fill().forEach((_, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute('data-index', i)
    li.classList.add(`list${i}`);
    tempArray.push(li)
  })
  return tempArray;
}


function shuffle(array) {
  let index = array.length - 1;
  while (index > 0) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (index + 1));
    [array[index], array[randomIndex]] = [array[randomIndex], array[index]]
    index--;
  }
  return array;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add CSS transition to elements created by JavaScript, you need to add the transition property to the CSS style of the element. In your case, you can add the transition property to the "li" element style in the createImageTiles() function like this:

```
<div class="wrap-all">
  <ul class="image-container">
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>

<script>
  const container = document.querySelector(".image-container");
  const wrapAll = document.querySelector(".wrap-all");
  const tileCount = 16;

  let tiles = [];

  setGame();

  function setGame() {
    tiles = createImageTiles();
    tiles.forEach(tile => container.appendChild(tile));
  }

  wrapAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // select all "li" elements
    const liList = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    // add delay to transition for all "li" elements
    liList.forEach(li => li.style.transitionDelay = "0.2s");

    shuffle(tiles).forEach(tile => container.appendChild(tile));

    setTimeout(() => {
      container.innerHTML = "";
      setGame();
    }, 3000)
  })

  function createImageTiles() {
    const tempArray = [];
    Array(tileCount).fill().forEach((_, i) => {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      li.setAttribute('data-index', i)
      li.classList.add(`list${i}`);
      // add transition property to "li" element
      li.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
      tempArray.push(li)
    })
    return tempArray;
  }

  function shuffle(array) {
    let index = array.length - 1;
    while (index > 0) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (index + 1));
      [array[index], array[randomIndex]] = [array[randomIndex], array[index]]
      index--;
    }
    return array;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But somehow, it doesn't make any difference when they move. There is still no delay... What can be a reason for this problem?